# What does !< or !> mean in C#?

Tags: c#, error-handling

I know it doesn't exist in C# as an operator but it's not an error.
What does it mean?

```
using System;

namespace MyApp // Note: actual namespace depends on the project name.
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 2;
            int b = 4;
            int c = 5;

            if (a + b!>c)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("abc");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this compiles, it's definitely not C# 4. It's telling the compiler that `b` isn't `null`.

Comment: ! is logical negation, so negation of more than is less than... Btw, this is the first time that I see this kind of usage :D

Comment: @j.v. `!` is the [null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving).

Comment: @shingo you are right, just tested... it's stupid though that is used on non-nullable types in this case, but it compiles...

Comment: @j.v. If you try to run the code (which i know see you did) above `a + b! > c` comes out as true. Since there is already a negative version of both `>` and `<` this refers to  a null-forgiving operator. And has (in this sample code) no added benefit as far as I know. It is just formatted in a non proper way to show what the `!` belongs to